# Logic for a function in AS3 giving error for unknown reason

Tags: actionscript-3, events

**What I have:**

1. Buyer class. Objects of Buyer class are generated along game time and stored in the array : Buyers.
2. Shop class. Objects of Shop class are generated in the begining of the program.
3. Event "Assign Event" that nullifies the "shoppingBuyer" of Buyer type of Shop Object.

**What I'm trying to do:**

When we click a buyer, if the buyer's 2 conditions are fullfilled 1. y>=377 or  enteredMall==true, the buyer is selected and saved into selectedBuyer variable of Buyer.

After that, when I click a shop, if the shop's Buyer object "shoppingBuyer" is null, The selected Buyer is assigned as the shoppingBuyer and the timer runs. Otherwise message is displayed that this cannot happen.

When the timer is over, a function is launched "shopGetOut" which lets the buyer out of the shop and nullifies the buyer of shop and shop of buyer and resets the shop in such a way that it can be acccesible to other Buyer object as well now.

**Where I'm getting error:**

Initially, everything works good. But as more and more Buyer objects are included, somehow the shoppingBuyer is not being assigned and stays null but this doesn't happen all the times only few times.

Error when I trace/ access shoppingBuyer of a specefic Shop object :

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>       at FashionFrenzy/shopGetOut()
>       at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
>       at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
>       at Shop/addTime()
>       at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
>       at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

Like this when it traces displayAll() of Shop:

Correct display: 
Shop Name: Tops
Shopping Buyer: null

Error display:
Shop Name: Movies
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at FashionFrenzy/shopGetOut()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at Shop/addTime()
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

and sometimes even Shop name isn't traced out as well

**My Code:**

*My functions:*

When Shop is clicked:

```
public function shopselected(event: SelectEvent): void {



  if (SelectedBuyer != null) { //checks if we actually selected a buyer before we clicked a shop

    if (SelectedBuyer.previousShop == event.selectedshop) {
      trace("You just went in there"); // this is to not let a buyer enter the same shop they have been before to.

    } else {
      SelectedBuyer.currentShop = event.selectedshop; // changes the current shop which was previously null to the shop they are in right now

      SelectedBuyer.shopping = true;  
      SelectedShop = event.selectedshop; // the clicked shop becomes selected shop
      trace(SelectedShop.ShopName);

      if (SelectedShop.ShoppingBuyer == null && SelectedShop.ShopName != "Counter") { //check if someone is already shopping in that shop or if it's the counter
        SelectedShop.ShoppingBuyer = SelectedBuyer;

        SelectedShop.InWork(); // this starts a timer of the shop and when desired timer is reached, it dispatches the ShopOverEvent which runs the function  shopGetOut.

        if (SelectedBuyer.enteredMall == true) {

          dispatchEvent(new AssignEvent(AssignEvent.MIDDLE, SelectedBuyer.previousShop.ShopNumber)); //this has nothing to do with my probelm
        } else {
          dispatchEvent(new AssignEvent(AssignEvent.ENTRY, SelectedBuyer.laneNo)); //this has nothing to do with my probelm
        }

        SelectedBuyer.enteredMall = true;
        SelectedBuyer.x = SelectedShop.Displayart.x + 20;
        SelectedBuyer.y = SelectedShop.Displayart.y - 20;










      } else { //this all is working fine from here.
        if (SelectedShop.ShopName == "Counter") {
          SelectedBuyer.x = SelectedShop.Displayart.x + 20;
          SelectedBuyer.y = SelectedShop.Displayart.y - 20;
          if (SelectedBuyer.enteredMall) {
            dispatchEvent(new AssignEvent(AssignEvent.MIDDLE, SelectedBuyer.previousShop.ShopNumber));
          } else {
            dispatchEvent(new AssignEvent(AssignEvent.ENTRY, SelectedBuyer.laneNo));
          }

          removeChild(SelectedBuyer);
        } else {
          trace("Someone is already there");
        }


      }
    }
    removeChild(SelectBuyerOverlay);
  } else {
    trace("Please Select a Buyer first");
  }
  SelectedBuyer = null;
  SelectedShop = null;

}
```

When timer of shop reaches limit while buyer is shopping:

```
public function shopGetOut(event: ShopOverEvent): void {


  event.shopEnd.shopTimer.stop(); // the timer which was started is set off.
  event.shopEnd.ShoppingBuyer.y += 80; // the buyer is shifted out of the shop
  event.shopEnd.ShoppingBuyer.shopping = false; // buyer is no longer shopping 
  event.shopEnd.ShoppingBuyer.previousShop = event.shopEnd; //current shop is made previous shop 
  event.shopEnd.ShoppingBuyer.currentShop = null; // current shop is made null

  dispatchEvent(new AssignEvent(AssignEvent.MIDDLE, event.shopEnd.ShopNumber)); // this nullifies previous shop nothing to do with my problem 

  event.shopEnd = null; 


}
```

I'll be glad if I get to do the same with a better and easy code without the error coming.

Comment: As a tip, in the future, consider following the convention of making all instance and property/method names start with a lower case letter, and make all Class names start with an upper case letter.  It makes code readability easier (and allows for proper code highlighting).

Comment: Okay I'll do that from my next file. But can you please help me out?

Comment: On a side note, please post only the portion of code that "misbehaves" instead of posting the entire source of your project. Also consider if this part depends on some other code (functions primarily) that can return unexpected values and post that code as well. No one needs to sift through your entire project in order to find a typo, but if you're desperate, try localizing the place where that typo might be, then someone might be more eager to help you.

Comment: The problem specifically comes with the function shopGetOut() function.

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question because you've posted so many code snippets.  If you took out everything that you know for certain isn't part of the problem (maybe use paste bin or something to link to the entire source code for reference) and put code comments explaining what your vars and methods are trying to accomplish,  that would make it much easier.

Comment: @LDMS I have removed unwanted code and added comments on required statements for better understanding as you said.